Mount SFTP directory in NFS Share
Here's my issue :
I have setup an SFTP with chroot directory is /sftp/usersftp In this chroot directory i have two subdirectory IN/OUT
On the same serveur i had created a user with $HOME=/data/username Then i share that $HOME with NFS /etc/exports = /data/username ip_client(rw,sync,no_root_squash)
I access that NFS from a windows server and that work perfectly
Now in that NFS share i also had to see the IN/OUT directory from the windows server and they have to be in Read/Write
First i try symbolic link but they are not seen from windows side
For solving that i created two directory IN/OUT in $HOME and make a bind mount from sftp directory to $HOME like that : mount --bind /sftp/usersftp/IN /data/username/IN mount --bind /sftp/usersftp/OUT /data/username/OUT
From the Windowd side i correctly see that two directory but i'am note able to see the files in that directory or create file it tell me that i have no rights
I have tried all this options for the NFS Share but unsuccessfully : (rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=0,anongid=0) I also try no_root_squash/nolock
A little bit help will be very nice PLZ
